# how to display records which is present in employee but not present in department table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to get records which is present in employees table but not in department
i.e (Employees - department)

output should be like this

Employee(ID,Name), Department(Id,Name)

i tried this

```
select * from Employee   as e 

  left  join Department as d on e.DeptId = d.ID
```

sample data

```
ID  Name    DeptId  Salary  ID  Name
1   krishna  1     5000     1   developer
2   rakesh   2     8000     2   trainer
3   sanjay   3     9000     3   programmer
4   swapna   4     6000     4   seo
6   shiva    6     4000     NULL    NULL
```

i want to show records of shiva because he is in table employee but not in department table in sql server

Comment: "i want to show records of show because"?

Comment: view this: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=https://sqlwithmanoj.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/sql_joins.jpg&imgrefurl=http://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/cross-join-2/&h=760&w=966&tbnid=JUk23PWAlDNzJM:&tbnh=144&tbnw=184&usg=___KvzxjFcTAcQMRlWegdb3lvo0b4=&docid=c_yhQ2eJWJjsrM&itg=1&client=firefox-a&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ9QEwAGoVChMIs6zr7IzsxwIVhQuOCh0xaAhW

Comment: How these tables are linked? what's the foreign key? Shouldn't you have dept in employee table?

Comment: @InsaneSkulll I always use this image. was about to comment the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use an `OUTER JOIN` as you've already done and filter by `d.ID is null`(as [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32497428/284240) has already shown). Or use `NOT EXISTS` which is my favorite:

```
select e.*
from Employee e 
where not exists
(
    select 1 from Department d
    where e.DeptId = d.ID
)
```

Pros and cons of all approaches:

- [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: error - The column prefix 'd' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Comment: @krishnamohan: sorry, copy-paste issue. Try again. Maybe the `NOT EXISTS` is not the best approach for you because you also want the columns from department, even if they are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a little  difficulty understanding the question but with your existing query a WHERE clause could be used to only show records that don't have an appartment.

```
select * from Employee   as e 
left  join Department as d on e.DeptId = d.ID 
WHERE d.ID is null
```

Alternatively

```
select 
* 
from Employee as e 
WHERE e.ID not in (SELECT d.ID FROM Department d)
```

Comment: NOT IN is a bit dangerous if d.id is nullable. Consider adding where id is not null to sub-select to make query "null-safe".

Comment: Great article @TimSchmelter (sorry I can't comment directly to your post yet) Thanks for the link!